# Is there any APIs from Jenkins that will give the list of API Tokens present in the configure tab?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Can some help me, if anyone knows that, if there any API from Jenkins that will give me the list of api tokens present in the User >> Configure tab?

[image]

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I am not sure about API access but i have a groovy script that you can run using the python API to get the list of token from any user id.

Comment: Can you help share some details about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following groovy script.

```
user = hudson.model.User.get('username')
prop = user.getProperty(jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty)
tokenList = prop.getTokenStore().getTokenListSortedByName()
tokenList.each() {
println(it.getName())
}
```

Usually i run this from admin to get stats of each token and who it belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t know the username and you want to list tokens from all users, you can use this snippet in the groovy console

```
import hudson.model.User   
User.getAll().each { user ->   
  prop = user.getProperty(jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty)
  tokenList = prop.getTokenStore().getTokenListSortedByName()
  tokenList.each { token ->
    println("$user -> $token.name")
  }
}
```